# AJAX data coming null on first request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

guys! I'm heaving a problem with my ajax call to Java backend.

I have this AJAX sending this "plugin" to my backend:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'myUrl',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            assync: true,

            data: {
                plugin: hasPLuginNavigator
            },

            success(data) {
                console.log(data);

            },

            error(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
         });
```

in my Java class servlet I got that line command:

`String hasPlugin = request.getParameter("plugin");`

In a first request, he return to me null. After I repeat the process and go to the page, returns to me correctly. I don't know why, please help.

Comment: can u add backend code if you have access?

Comment: This `assync: true,` should be `async: true,`. Try `async: false` as well.